# Finding the matrix form of Brinkmann's metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have the following problem: given Brinkmann's metric expressed as
$$ds^2 = du dv - \delta_{i j} dx^i dx^j - K_{i j}(u) x^i x^j du^2$$
and $i,j=1,2, $  I have to find it's matricial form; my question is the following: how I'm supposed to do that?

I know that the general expression is $$ds^2 = g_{i j} dx^i dx^j$$
but I do not see how to write $g_{ij}$.

*Subsidiary question: why is this metric useful to study gravitational waves in the void?*

Thanks you!

Comment: I'd address you to [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) about out "homework-like-questions" policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinates are $X = (v,x,y,u)$ and the metric with respect to these coordinates is $ds^2 = g_{ij}dX^idX^j$. So the matrix of the metric tensor looks like:

$$ g_{ij} = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
 0   & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
 0   & -1 & 0 & 0   \\
 0   & 0  & -1& 0  \\
1/2& 0  & 0  & -K_{ij}x^i x^j \end{array} \right) $$

It is to be expected that $v$ and $u$ have some relationship with $t$ and $z$, but in this example Brinkmann's coordinates are to be used, i.e.: $X = (v,x,y,u)$. Moreover realize  $K_{ij}x^i x^j \equiv \sum\limits_{i,j}K_{ij}x^i x^j$ is just another coefficient (matrix element) of the metric tensor.